# How to prevent command line window exist after executing one command?

Tags: java, maven, batch-file

In a Windows bat file:

```
mvn.bat install
java -jar build.jar
pause
```

The command line window exist after executing `mvn.bat install`, how to let it proceed with execution of remain commands?

Comment: Try `call mvn.bat install`, but I don't remember Windows very well.

Comment: @DaveNewton then what he is doing now ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your problem is that when you invoke mvn command you never go back to your script again.

Try using the call command e.g.:

```
call mvn install
```

This will invoke mvn install command and then return back to your script.